# encontrar valor que menos se repete em lista

Tags: python, lista, random

Tenho que sortear mil números entre 0 e 100, e apontar quais números foram mais/menos repetidos e o maior e menor valor, mas não encontrei maneira de mostrar o que foi menos sorteado.

```
import random
lista = []
n = 1000
for y in range(n):
    num = random.randint(1, 100)
    lista.append(num)
    #print(lista)
print(f"O maior número sorteado é: {max(lista)}\nO menor número sorteado é: {min(lista)}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Em estatística, a frequência(ou frequência absoluta) de um evento *i*
>   é o número *nᵢ* de vezes que o evento ocorreu em um experimento ou
>   estudo. Ou seja a quantidade de vezes que esse valor aparece na
>   amostra.
>   <sub>[Wikipédia: Frequência (estatística)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequ%C3%AAncia_(estat%C3%ADstica)#:~:text=de%20vezes%20que%20o%20evento%20ocorreu%20em%20um%20experimento%20ou,valor%20aparece%20na%20amostra%20total.)</sub>

O que ocorre é nem sempre aparecerá apenas um número com a menor frequência. Pode ocorrer de um ou mais números possuírem a mesma frequência.

Então para encontrar os números que ocorram menos vezes em sua lista primeiro você tem que computar a frequência de cada elemento da lista e depois analisar qual ou quais os elementos que possuem a menor frequência.

Para computar a frequência de cada elemento pode ser utilizado o método [list.count()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html), que devolve o número de vezes em que um elemento aparece na lista e ir guardando o resultado em um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) onde as chaves são os números da lista e os valores são as respectivas frequências.

Para encontrar a menor frequência dentre os valores do dicionário pode usar a função builtin [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min), que retorna o menor valor de um iterável, e usar esse valor para encontrar as chaves.

```
import random
lista = []
n = 1000
for y in range(n):
    num = random.randint(1, 100)
    lista.append(num)
    #print(lista)
print(f"O maior número sorteado é: {max(lista)}\nO menor número sorteado é: {min(lista)}")

frequencia = {} #Dicionário onde serão contabilizadas as frequências

#Para cada elemento da lista...
for n in lista:
  if (n not in frequencia): #Se a frequência ainda não foi computada
    frequencia[n] = lista.count(n) #Conta o número de vezes que o elemento apareceu

#Obtém a menor frequência.
menorFrequencia = min(frequencia.values())

#Cria uma lista contendo os números que menos apareceram.
menosOcorreram = [k for k,v in frequencia.items() if v == menorFrequencia]

print(f'Menor frequência {menosOcorreram} com {menorFrequencia} ocorrência(s)')
```

Teste no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/MenorFrequencia).