# Obter o elemento mais frequente e menos frequente de uma lista, além do maior e menor

Tags: python, lista

Como consigo encontrar qual o maior e menor número, além do mais frequente e o menos frequente, em uma lista qualquer?

Código atual:

```
import random

maiorNumero = 0
menorNumero = 100

arrayNumeros = []

print("Os numeros gerados foram: \n")
for x in range(1,11):
    arrayNumeros.append(random.randint(0,10))
    print(arrayNumeros)


print(" ")
print (f"O maior número gerado foi: {maiorNumero}\n")
print (f"O menor número gerado foi: {menorNumero}\n")
print(f"O número sorteado mais vezes foi: {maisSorteado}\n")
print(f"O número sorteado mais vezes foi: {menosSorteado}\n")
```

Comment: Ontem eu respondi uma pergunta similar a essa. Veja se ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/456064/137387

Answer (score 2):

Para contar a frequência de todos os elementos de uma lista, basta usar um [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Em seguida, para obter os mais e menos frequentes, use o método [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
import random
from collections import Counter

# gera 10 números aleatórios entre 0 e 10
numeros = random.choices(range(11), k=10)
print(f'Os numeros gerados foram: {numeros}')

frequencias = Counter(numeros).most_common()
mais_frequente, menos_frequente = frequencias[0], frequencias[-1]
print(f'O número que ocorre mais vezes é {mais_frequente[0]}, ocorrendo {mais_frequente[1]} vezes')
print(f'O número que ocorre menos vezes é {menos_frequente[0]}, ocorrendo {menos_frequente[1]} vezes')
```

`most_common` retorna uma lista de tuplas, sendo que cada tupla contém o elemento e a respectiva quantidade de vezes que ele ocorre. Assim, o mais frequente é o primeiro elemento desta lista, e o menos frequente é o último.

As outras respostas sugerem usar o método `count` da lista, mas esta é uma maneira ineficiente, porque cada vez que `count` é chamado, ele percorre toda a lista para obter a contagem de um único elemento. Ou seja, você estará percorrendo a lista várias vezes, para obter a contagem de todos os elementos.
Pior, para um elemento que ocorre mais de uma vez, você estará obtendo a contagem do mesmo várias vezes. Isso não só é desnecessário, como extremamente ineficiente - claro que [para listas pequenas nem fará tanta diferença](https://blog.codinghorror.com/everything-is-fast-for-small-n/), mas para listas maiores, a diferença é gritante. E nem precisa ser tão grande assim: fazendo um teste com uma lista de 2000 elementos, [o `Counter` foi **muito** mais rápido](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/ImaginativeCyanProcedures#main.py) (algumas centenas de vezes mais rápido). Se aumentar para 10 mil elementos, [a diferença se torna maior ainda](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/ShabbyFaroffPolygon#main.py).

> *Quando você percorre uma lista várias vezes sem necessidade, está criando uma variação do chamado ["Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm"](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). O problema é que muitas vezes só testamos com listas pequenas e não notamos o problema, mas se for fazer isso em grandes volumes de dados, aí fará toda a diferença.*

Sendo assim, usar um `Counter` é melhor porque você só percorre a lista uma vez, obtendo a contagem de todos os elementos. Mas ainda temos que resolver o caso de empates, quando mais de um elemento é o mais (ou o menos) frequente. Como `most_common` já retorna os elementos na ordem (do mais frequente para o menos frequente), basta percorrer a lista partindo do início (ou do fim) e parar quando encontrar um com contagem diferente:

```
frequencias = Counter(numeros).most_common()
mais_frequente, menos_frequente = frequencias[0], frequencias[-1]

print(f'Números mais frequentes (ocorrem {mais_frequente[1]} vezes)')
for f in frequencias:
    if f[1] == mais_frequente[1]:
        print(f[0])
    else:
        break
print(f'Números menos frequentes (ocorrem {menos_frequente[1]} vezes)')
for f in reversed(frequencias):
    if f[1] == menos_frequente[1]:
        print(f[0])
    else:
        break
```

Por fim, repare também que para gerar uma lista com 10 números aleatórios entre 0 e 10, você pode usar [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices), passando `range(11)`, que gera um `range` com os números entre 0 e 10 (já que um `range` não inclui o valor final). Lembrando que `random.choices` está disponível a partir do Python 3.6. Para versões anteriores, você pode simplificar seu *loop*, trocando-o por uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
# gera 10 números aleatórios entre 0 e 10
numeros = [ random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(10) ]
```

---

Ainda dá para otimizar mais, pois se você usar o `Counter` para obter as frequências, e depois usar [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) e [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) para obter o maior e menor elemento, estará percorrendo a lista 3 vezes (uma para o `Counter`, outra para `max` e outra para `min`). Se quiser fazer tudo em um único *loop*, aí terá que fazer tudo manualmente (mas dependendo do tamanho da lista, pode compensar não ter que percorrê-la várias vezes):

```
contagens = Counter()
maior = float('-inf') # infinito negativo
menor = float('inf') # infinito

for n in numeros:
    contagens.update([n])
    if n > maior:
        maior = n
    if n < menor:
        menor = n

frequencias = contagens.most_common()
mais_frequente, menos_frequente = frequencias[0], frequencias[-1]
print(f'Números mais frequentes (ocorrem {mais_frequente[1]} vezes)')
for f in frequencias:
    if f[1] == mais_frequente[1]:
        print(f[0])
    else:
        break
print(f'Números menos frequentes (ocorrem {menos_frequente[1]} vezes)')
for f in reversed(frequencias):
    if f[1] == menos_frequente[1]:
        print(f[0])
    else:
        break

print(f'O maior número é {maior}')
print(f'O menor número é {menor}')
```

Este *loop* fica um pouco menos eficiente do que usar o `Counter` diretamente, mas ainda sim, [muito mais rápido](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/CornsilkMurkyDistributeddatabase#main.py) do que usar `set` e/ou `count`.

Answer (score 1):

Em python, quando temos uma lista e desejamos saber o maior valor, podemos utilizar o método max. Segue a [documentação para referência](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).

Assim, utilizando o seu código, para encontrar o maior valor, podemos simplesmente utilizar a função max.

```
print("O maior número gerado foi: {}".format(max(arrayNumeros)))
print("O menor número gerado foi: {}".format(min(arrayNumeros)))
```

Quando você fala que deseja mostrar os elementos que mais se repetem, estamos nos referindo à moda de um conjunto. Devemos ter cuidado pois o elemento que mais se repete pode ser mais de um, neste caso o retorno deve ser um conjunto retornando os elementos que mais se repetem.

```
print("O número sorteado mais vezes foi: {}".format(max(set(arrayNumeros), key=arrayNumeros.count)))
print("O número sorteado menos vezes foi: {}".format(min(set(arrayNumeros), key=arrayNumeros.count)))
```

Caso esteja utilizando o `python >= 3.8` para encontrar todas as modas de um conjunto pode-se utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
from statistics import multimode
arrayNumeros = [3,9,1,9,7,8,10,4,5,4]
multimode(arrayNumeros)
#[9, 4]
```

Comment: Certo, entendi perfeitamente! E para saber qual número foi mais sorteado e o menos sorteado?

Comment: Está na resposta.

Comment: Desculpa minha falta de atenção, entendi perfeitamente! E no caso de querer representar este conjunto de itens? Faço com o laço For?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Basta utilizar as funções [`min`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_min.asp) e [`max`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_max.asp) para obter o menor e maior valor de uma lista ou qualquer outro objeto iterável como tuplas, dicts, sets, etc. Veja o código abaixo:

```
import random

# Gera uma lista com dez número aleatórios entre [0-10]
numeros = [random.randint(0, 10) for x in range(11)]

# Obtém o menor e maior valor da lista.
menor = min(numeros)
maior = max(numeros)

print("Os numeros gerados foram:", *numeros)
print ("O maior número gerado foi:", maior)
print ("O menor número gerado foi:", menor)
```

Para saber qual foi o valor mais sorteado e menos sorteado utilize o método [`count`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_count.asp) para contar o número de vezes em que um valor aparece na lista. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
# O código abaixo obtém o valor que mais se repete e o que menos se repete na lista.

mais, menos = numeros[0], numeros[0]

for numero in numeros:
    mais = numero if numeros.count(numero) > numeros.count(mais) else mais
    menos = numero if numeros.count(numero) < numeros.count(menos) else menos
```

Comment: Certo, entendi perfeitamente! 

E para saber qual número foi mais sorteado e o menos sorteado?

Comment: Coloquei na resposta a forma de se contar a quantidade de elementos em uma lista.

Answer (score 0):

De forma mais simples do que as outras respostas, você pode usar `max` e `min` pra tudo. Essas funções possuem um parâmetro `key` que pode ser passado para pegar o número com mais/menos ocorrências.

```
print(max(numeros))
print(min(numeros))
print(max(numeros, key=numeros.count))
print(min(numeros, key=numeros.count))
```